# Is it possible make express module listen on Unix domain socket?

Tags: node.js, express, unix-socket

Is it possible make express module listen on Unix domain socket, instead of TCP port, something like this below code

```
var express = require('express');

var app=express();

function getUserHome() {
    return process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE;
}

var socketPath = getUserHome() + '/socket_log_svr';

app.listen(socketpath);
```

Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried it? The underlying code to `app.listen` is just the listen method in the `http` module, which [states that](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_handle_callback) the handle can be set to a server or a socket.